# Writing to a file doesn't work. When using the function read() it gives no output

Tags: python

```
import random, time, pickle #Imports needed libaries
from random import * #Imports all from random

filename = ("char.txt")
charList = []#Sets blank list
charListstr = ''.join(charList)#Makes new list a string so it can be written to file

def write():
        creation()
        charw = open(filename, 'w')
        charw.write(charListstr)
        charw.close()


def read():
        charr = open(filename, 'r')
        lines = charr.read()
        charr.close()


def creation():
        charListinput = input("What would you like your charcater to be called?")
        charList.append(charListinput)
```

I am trying to get a program to accept a charcaters name and then append that data to a list. I then need the list to write to a .txt file so that it can be read externally by the user. But when the function is ran there are no erros but read() just gives a blank output. I am terrible at Python so any help would be useful.

Comment: `charListstr` is always empty. If you write an empty string to the file you will get an empty string back when reading the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charListstr` is always the empty string, because you only evaluate it once and at that time the list is empty. You should join your list in your `write` function. Also, you're not returning anything from `read`, so you would have no output even if you did save something to the file.

You will need to fix both problems before you can have some output.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from `read()` Add `return lines` to the end.

You might also want to use the `with` statement to open the file. It closes it automatically and can save some headaches in the future. You should also pass the file as a parameter in the function as it will make your code more flexible.

```
def read(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        lines = file.read()
        return lines
```

Comment: Ok I added that, all that returns now is '' ?

Comment: What file are your trying to read? Show us an example in your question.